# When i run exe with dynamic args powershell trim command output. How to fix?

Tags: windows, powershell

I have script running some command through &
for example

```
$output = & rc.exe /d N_MAJOR=1 /d N_MINOR=0 /d N_PATCH=0 version.rc
```

`$output` variable contain trimmed command output such as

```
Microsoft (R) Windows (R) Resource Compiler Version 6.0.5724.0

Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.



d:\tfs\
```

but it must contain

```
Microsoft (R) Windows (R) Resource Compiler Version 6.0.5724.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.


d:\tfs\...\version.rc(1) : error RC2135 : file not found: xx.ico
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Any difference if you pipe to `out-string` or, `out-host`? `$output = & rc.exe /d N_MAJOR=1 /d N_MINOR=0 /d N_PATCH=0 version.rc | out-string`

Comment: This might help ... [about_Redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection?view=powershell-7.1)

Comment: Or you could try to use `Start-Process` and redirect the standard output and the error output into files.

Comment: `out-string` and `out-host` trim output.
`Start-process` need test it

Comment: `Start-process` work fine. Post this as answer